# Too many apache processes, killing the CPU

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, high-load

I am noticed that too many apache processes killing the CPU in my dedicated server.

```
14193 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     66.1  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
14128 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.9  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
14136 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.9  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
14129 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.8  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
13419 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.7  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
13421 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.7  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
13426 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.7  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
13428 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.7  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
13429 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.7  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
12173 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.5  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
14073 (Trace) (Kill)    nobody  0     65.5  0.0 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL
```

I am getting high load email notification from cpanel during the day.

FROM httpd.conf

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf"
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_2.conf"



LoadModule bwlimited_module modules/mod_bwlimited.so

LoadModule h264_streaming_module /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
AddHandler h264-streaming.extensions .mp4

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf"
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/errordocument.conf"


ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?controlpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?kpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecontrolpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securewhm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/swhmredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/?whm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/whmredirect.cgi

RewriteEngine on
AddType text/html .shtml

Alias /akopia /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/interchange/share/akopia/
Alias /bandwidth /usr/local/bandmin/htdocs/
Alias /img-sys /usr/local/cpanel/img-sys/
Alias /interchange /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/interchange/share/interchange/
Alias /interchange-5 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/interchange/share/interchange-5/
Alias /java-sys /usr/local/cpanel/java-sys/
Alias /mailman/archives /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/
Alias /pipermail /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/
Alias /sys_cpanel /usr/local/cpanel/sys_cpanel/


ScriptAlias /cgi-sys /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/
ScriptAlias /mailman /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/cgi-bin/


<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options All
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files ~ "^error_log$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all

    Satisfy All
</Files>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>

<IfModule prefork.c>
    Mutex default mpm-accept

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_log_config.c>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    CustomLog logs/access_log common

</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
    Mutex default mpm-accept

</IfModule>

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#   Direct modifications to the Apache configuration file may be lost upon subsequent regeneration of the       #
#   configuration file. To have modifications retained, all modifications must be checked into the              #
#   configuration system by running:                                                                            #
#       /usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update                                                    #
#   To see if your changes will be conserved, regenerate the Apache configuration file by running:              #
#       /usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf                                                                 #
#   and check the configuration file for your alterations. If your changes have been ignored, then they will    #
#   need to be added directly to their respective template files.                                               #
#                                                                                                               #
#   It is also possible to add custom directives to the various "Include" files loaded by this httpd.conf       #
#   For detailed instructions on using Include files and the apache_conf_distiller with the new configuration   #
#   system refer to the documentation at: http://www.cpanel.net/support/docs/ea/ea3/customdirectives.html       #
#                                                                                                               #
#   This configuration file was built from the following templates:                                             #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/main.default                                                                #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/main.local                                                                  #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/vhost.default                                                               #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/vhost.local                                                                 #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/ssl_vhost.default                                                           #
#     /var/cpanel/templates/apache2/ssl_vhost.local                                                             #
#                                                                                                               #
#  Templates with the '.local' extension will be preferred over templates with the '.default' extension.        #
#  The only template updated by the apache_conf_distiller is main.default.                                      #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #


PidFile logs/httpd.pid
# Defined in /var/cpanel/cpanel.config: apache_port
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
User nobody
Group nobody
ExtendedStatus On
ServerAdmin utkudalmaz@gmail.com
ServerName server.powerlabel.net
LogLevel warn

# These can be set in WHM under 'Apache Global Configuration'
Timeout 300

ServerSignature On



<IfModule prefork.c>


</IfModule>







RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap LeechProtect prg:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
Mutex file:/usr/local/apache/logs rewrite-map

<IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
UserDir disabled
</IfModule>

# DirectoryIndex is set via the WHM -> Service Configuration -> Apache Setup -> DirectoryIndex Priority
DirectoryIndex index.html.var index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm index.php5 Default.html Default.htm home.html

# SSLCipherSuite can be set in WHM under 'Apache Global Configuration'

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/usr/local/apache/logs/stapling_cache_shmcb(256000)
SSLSessionCache shmcb:/usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_gcache_data_shmcb(1024000)

SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
Mutex                   file:/usr/local/apache/logs ssl-cache
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin



    # Defined in /var/cpanel/cpanel.config: apache_ssl_port
    Listen 0.0.0.0:443
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl


AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .plx .ppl .perl
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-tar .tgz
AddType text/vnd.wap.wml .wml
AddType image/vnd.wap.wbmp .wbmp
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript .wmls
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc .wmlc
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc .wmlsc

<Location /whm-server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>



# SUEXEC is supported

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf"
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_2.conf"
```

What can cause this and how can i fix it ?

Comment: paste your relevant httpd.conf, as well as memory and cpu cores available. what handler are you running? mod_php? what mpm? prefork? i will say everyone i meet who has apache load issues is very happy when they switch to nginx.

Comment: Server Version: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Server MPM: prefork

Comment: 32 gb ram - 8 CPU

Comment: http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/tuning-the-apache-prefork-mpm/

Comment: should i switch it to nginx ?

Comment: well, being that i see you use php (Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf").... i can say from experience that having a php-fpm pool behind a tier of nginx boxes is the way to scale php massively

Comment: probably stupid search engine bots scouring your pages or script kiddies trying to brute your member logins.  Did you check your access logs during times of heavy loads to see what they're hitting?

Answer (score 2):

Before doing massive changes, try to figure out if this load is valid.

I had a similar problem where bots were abusing the login page, causing load to my server and eventually had OOM killer killing apache children.  I started monitoring the apache log with fail2ban so to add an iptables DROP rule after 6 POST requests on the login php script. Load dropped from about 30-40 req/sec to 2-6 req/sec (which was the actual valid traffic)